# Zoom Meeting thumbnails

Tags: zoom-meeting

Maybe for you is a solve problem but ask you why when i work with zoom in Windows can see in my monitor 49 thumbnails but in ubuntu in the same pc i see only 25. My pc is with Intel HD video inside pc.
Any solve?
Thanks

Comment: You can see here https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115003322603-Changing-the-video-layout-of-the-Zoom-Room-display-Active-Speaker-View-and-Gallery-View-
at the "Gallery View" section. 

"Gallery View displays up to 25 participants per screen by default or up to 49 participants per screen if enabled in the settings. "

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution. When using Teams in Linux, you depend on the Linux version of the Teams' application as provided by Microsoft.

The Linux version is essentially a wrapped version of the web app and may not have all features of their dedicated Teams' application on the Windows desktop.

However, with respect to essential functionality, you are more than 95% set with the Linux or Web version.